# Why am I getting gray map after loading google map for second time by click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

On my contact page, I have 3-4 addresses. I want to show one address on google map initially, on page load. And when the user clicks on different address then marker changes and moves to that address.

Initially, on page load, I am getting google map correctly. Map shows everything perfectly fine. But when I click on different addresses to move marker, marker moves but map gets gray colored. I mean the map is not showing perfectly as it shows for the first time.

Here is the screenshot for both

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEk3R.png) (Initially, Map loads perfectly fine)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWInY.png) (But When I click on address to change map location it shows gray colored map)

Here is my code

```
$(function(){

var map;
var marker;
// Load Map function
function loadMap(lat,long, fullAddress) {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("store-map");
    let latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latLong,
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLong,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: "Address"
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //Create and open InfoWindow.
    infoWindow.setContent(fullAddress);
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

}

var defaultAddress = "448-451, Udyog Vihar, Phase - V</br>Gurugram, Haryana- 122001",
        defaultLat = "28.4759576",
        defaultLong = "77.0363467";
 on page load load google map with default address    
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', 
loadMap(defaultLat,defaultLong, defaultAddress));

// Get clickable item
var $locationItem = $('.store-location__item');
// On ckick of each address
$locationItem.on('click',function(event) {
    // event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    let lat = $(this).find('.lat').text();
    let long = $(this).find('.lat').text();
    let address = $(this).find('.store-location__address').html();
    console.log(lat, long, address);
    loadMap(lat,long,address);
});


});
```

Am I missing something? Why am I getting a gray colored map on click to change the location according to latitude and longitude after getting it from dom?

**Note**:

- I have given latitude and longitude in HTML which has opacity 0 and
  getting it on click to change the location
- I also tried to create a new marker and remove the previous marker
  instead of loading a new google map for performance but that is also
  giving gray color issue.
- I also tried to check css like 'overflow:visible' and
  'overflow:hidden' but nothing happens regarding gray color issue.

Comment: That's because you are passing the wrong value to `long`? You are still passing the `textContent` of the `.lat` element, which is incorrect: `let long = $(this).find('.lat').text();`

Comment: OMG! You're right. Terry- I love you. You saved my life. I am hitting my head for 10 hours looking for the solution. But I am a**hole. Thank again and God bless you.